# Why can't I open a image via the Terminal but can with Finder

Tags: terminal, finder, permission, preview, iterm

I'm running OSX 10.15.7.  I have a jpg file that I can open when double clicking on Finder, but if I run `open test.jpg` in the iTerm2 (also in Terminal.app) I get the following error

[image]

If I look at the permissions, I have access to it.

```
$ ls -lt test.jpg
-rw-r--r--@ 1 user  staff  232309 Aug 18 12:45 test.jpg
```

Question :

1. Why can I open this file via double clicking in Finder but not when I'm openning from the terminal?

**EDIT**
It turns out that after opening the file with Preview (via double clicking in Finder), I can then open `test.jpg` via `open test.jpg` in iTerm2.  This is even more perplexing.

Comment: What's the file path to the folder? Are you 'user'? Does the file have any ACLs?

Comment: I am `user`, the file is in the current working directory.  The permissions are shown above.

Comment: Is the 'current working directory' in ~/Documents, or ~/Downloads, for example, and does iTerm have permission to access those folders? Use `ls -le test.jpg` to see any ACLs.

Comment: It is in `~/Projects/path/to/some/custom/dir`.  I've been programming in this directory using iTerm. I can create a new file `~/Projects/path/to/some/custom/dir/newfile.txt` (which is at the same level as `test.jpg`).  The permissions using : `-rw-r--r--@ 1 user  staff  232309 Aug 18 12:45 test.jpg`

Comment: I can't replicate the behaviour with similar files here (using Terminal). What happens if you try with other image files, either in that dir, or elsewhere?

Comment: A different file `test2.jpg` in that same directory with perms `-rw-r--r--@ 1 user  staff  171090 Aug 18 12:45 test2.jpg` opens just fine.

Comment: Weird. What if you duplicate it in the Finder? And it's definitely a JPEG file -- e.g. not a PNG that's been wrongly labelled?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138937/discussion-between-irritable-phd-syndrome-and-benwiggy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured this out.  Notice the `@` at the end of the file permissions. This denotes extended attributes for the file.  E.g.

```
local: somedir $ ls -lt ch9.pdf
-rw-r--r--@ 1 user  staff  522580 Dec 20 06:53 ch9.pdf
local: somedir $ xattr -l ch9.pdf
com.apple.lastuseddate#PS:
00000000  86 A2 A1 B3 00 00 00 00 FB 51 00 00 00  |...c.....ZA/....|
00000010
com.apple.metadata:kMDLabel_l6hae2amcraik72lm3xdrm57ki:
00000000  F2 50 C3 33 F2 DC 4E 4E 7A 8B E2 4F CA  |.Q.3..MNZ<.{..O.|
.
. more output
.
000000F0  ED AB 46 F3 E4 F8 B4 1E 84                       |..F......|
com.apple.quarantine: 0082;623d1665;Preview;
```

Notice the last line, `com.apple.quarantine: 0082;623d1665;Preview;` is preventing us from opening this file. My guess this is new behavior from a file system update. We can 'fix' this behavior by simply removing it from the extended attributes, and the file will open from the command line just fine.

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine ch9.pdf
```